# Javascript skeleton for Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have a website which lets you design images by typing in a variety of text strings. I want my users to be able to run the site on any modern browser, and load and save their favorite setups. Right now I'm saving their data as JSON using LocalStorage, but that's a lousy way to go for many reasons. I'd prefer to let them read/write real files, but since the browser can't do that locally, Google Drive seemed like the best alternative (it's reliable and people can get more than enough free storage for this use).

I've read the Google Drive API docs, and read lots of questions and answers here, and I've seen lots of code snippets, but I'm finding it hard to assemble the information I'm finding into a working setup. I have credentials created at Google, but I'm frankly at a loss for how to proceed. I feel like I have a wealth of disparate details but no big picture.

For specificity, here's a trivial HTML/JS skeleton for reading and writing short text files. I'd like to fill in the button callbacks to make them work! Though I realize this is a bit more open-ended than a precise question, it's the integration that's the problem: I'm not sure which pieces are needed and how they need to coordinate. I think a working version of this skeleton would be useful to other people as well, offering a one-stop reference for how to manage basic file I/O on Google Drive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  // page load stuff here
});
var FileContents = "";
var FileName = "";  // from picker
function saveFile() {
  var success = false;
  FileContents = "this goes into a file";
  // success = open picker, name and save file on Google Drive
  if (success) alert("saved file named "+FileName+"!");
}
function loadFile() {
  var success = false;
  // success = open picker, choose file from Google Drive, load FileContents
  if (success) alert("loaded file named "+FileName+" with contents "+FileContents+"!");
}
function deleteFile() {
  var success = false;
  // success = open picker, choose file from Google Drive, delete it
  if (success) alert("deleted file named "+FileName");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="saveFile()">Save File</button>
<button onclick="loadFile()">Load File</button>
<button onclick="deleteFile()">Delete File</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you are asking for is basically a tutorial. Good you acknowledge that, but don't be surprised if you get some down votes too (not from me).

Comment: I don't need a tutorial in the classic sense of a narrated explanation of the concepts. That's already available, but in fragmented form. I'd be more than happy to see the code filled in with the minimum structure to make it work, even with no comments or explanatory text (not that such things would be unwelcome!).

Comment: its odd to receive so many upvotes. question is super broad and there are complete end to end samples in the official docs, like dr. edit

Comment: The GitHub page for DrEdit says that all the examples there are deprecated (and presumably out of date). Their replacement, QuickEditor, uses routines specific to AngularJS, which my site doesn't use. The rest of the official docs address issues in isolation and are hard to combine into a working program, which is why I asked the question. If you know where I can find a Javascript example like the skeleton I posted that doesn't depend on someone's framework, please post the URL!

Comment: Bump, I would like to know as well. For V3.